# Pandas Weird component datetime localized and apply

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, apply, python-datetime

I encounter a weird behaviour of the pandas apply on a non-naive datetime column (pandas version 0.24.1)

```
import pytz,tzlocal
from datetime import datetime,timezone

now=datetime.now(timezone.utc)
#now=datetime.now()
df=pd.DataFrame([{"now":now,"a":1},{"now":now,"a":3}])
def pr(x):
    print("* "*20)
    print(x.hour)
    print("# "*20)    

df["now"].apply(pr)
```

df :

```
    a   now
0   1   2020-04-23 12:07:28.749269
1   3   2020-04-23 12:07:28.749269
```

result with non-naive:

```
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
Int64Index([11, 11], dtype='int64')
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # 
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
11
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # 
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
11
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
```

result with naive :

```
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
12
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # 
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
12
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
```

Any idea why when it's a non-naive datetime the function of the apply is called on more time ?

When an error is raised in the first extra run it seem's to be catch by pandas and not re-raised .